# Woocommerce Return False with message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a function to remove the ability to purchase a product if its price is equal to, or greater than £50,000.

I would like to add a message where the add to cart button usually is, to say "**this product is over £50,000 - please contact us**"

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_cart_for_over_fifty_k', 10, 2 );

function disable_cart_for_over_fifty_k( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if( $product->get_price() >= 50000 )
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I think if you're more direct with your problem/question you are more likely to receive help. Is you current implementation not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `$message` variable that is empty for `true` and contains a messages (in HTML) for false:

PHP

```
$message = "";
...
function disable_cart_for_over_fifty_k( $purchasable, $product ){
    global $message;
    if( $product->get_price() >= 50000 ) {
        $message = "<p class='errorMessage'>This product is over £50,000 - please contact us</p>";
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML (*example*)

```
...
<?php echo $message; ?>
<button id="addCart">Add Cart</button>
...
```

You can also use a flag and choose what to `echo` if you want to hide "Add Cart" all together.

Answer (score 1):

You can display a message on any of the action hooks.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'so_contact_notice_30876596', 25 );
function so_contact_notice_30876596(){
    global $product;
    if( $product->get_price() >= 50000 ){
        echo "this product is over £50,000 - please contact us";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really the right way to do it and should be the correct answer. This helped a lot, thank you!